# Error when try to load html with htmlagiltypack

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to run this code

```
string path = "http://warisons.rssing.com/chan1729325/all_p43.html";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(path);
var div = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div");
foreach (var x in div)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.Attributes["class"].Value);
}
```

when I debug this code in `htmlDoc.LoadHtml(path);` I got this error

> Locating source for
>   'd:\SVN_CHECKOUT\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs'.
>   Checksum: MD5 {4e 14 d3 b d5 30 6e 2c bf 84 ab 8a 96 82 4a 8f} The
>   file
>   'd:\SVN_CHECKOUT\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs'
>   does not exist. Looking in script documents for
>   'd:\SVN_CHECKOUT\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for
>   'd:\SVN_CHECKOUT\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project. Looking in directory 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\'... Looking in
>   directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\crt\src\vccorlib\'... Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'... Looking in
>   directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'... Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include'... The debug
>   source files settings for the active solution indicate that the
>   debugger will not ask the user to find the file:
>   d:\SVN_CHECKOUT\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs.
>   The debugger could not locate the source file
>   'd:\SVN_CHECKOUT\htmlagilitypack\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlDocument.cs'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt to load html document from URI is incorrect.

Methof `HtmlDocument.LoadHtml` loads html from string provided, so its argument is html text itself, not URI.

To load html from provided URI you need something like:

```
string path = "http://warisons.rssing.com/chan1729325/all_p43.html";
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlWeb().Load(path);
```

Also note you can get `NullReferenceException` here:

```
x.Attributes["class"].Value
```

since you're not checking if there is `class` attribute (`x.Attributes["class"] != null`) before accessing its value.

Comment: it tried what you say and now i got same error about htmlweb
D:\Source\htmlagilitypack.new\Trunk\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlWeb.cs

Comment: Attempt I've suggested is working at my computer. Probably, something is wrong with your HtmlAgilityPack library. Have you built it by yourself oк downloaded from some resource? Try to remove reference to your existed dll and install new one from NuGet.

Comment: @TzurielYamin well, since I can't reproduce your error - I'm afraid I can't help you with this issue.

Comment: I found it!
just need to delete file named  "HtmlAgilityPack.pdb ".

Comment: I found it! just need to delete file named " HtmlAgilityPack.pdb ".wierd but i dont care

Comment: You save my day Yamin ! Was stuck with the same error and deleting the .pdb files have fixed the problem